# I want the layer1 to go down to the state1

Tags: android

Hi guys.

I posted my problems, but the answers I got don't work out.

All i want is that layer1 goes down the state 1, but its not working.

I hope you help me by editing the code cause I'm a beginner

This is the code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:padding="6dip" >


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:padding="6dip" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/secondLine"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:text="@string/state1"
android:textSize="16sp" />


<TextView
android:id="@+id/secondLine"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="26dip"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:singleLine="true"
android:text="@string/sayer1"
android:textSize="12sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: this is a duplicate post....

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.it will work for you.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:padding="6dip" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/secondLine"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:text="@string/state1"
android:textSize="16sp" />


<TextView
android:id="@+id/secondLine"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="26dip"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:singleLine="true"
android:text="@string/sayer1"
android:textSize="12sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

If your using `RelativeLayout` use `android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"` for `secondLine` `TextView`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:padding="6dip" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:text="state1"
android:textSize="16sp" />


<TextView
android:id="@+id/secondLine"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="26dip"
android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:singleLine="true"
android:text="sayer1"
android:textSize="12sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Or  If your using `LinearLayout` just use `android:orientation="vertical"`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="6dip" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:text="state1"
android:textSize="16sp" />


<TextView
android:id="@+id/secondLine"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="26dip"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:singleLine="true"
android:text="sayer1"
android:textSize="12sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```